# Laravel Return blank page

Tags: php, laravel

When I create a form, the website redirects me to the view page, however its just a white screen and I have to refresh for the view to show.

```
$modules = Module::all();
return response()->json(["modules"=> $modules]);
```

this is the code in my controller. How do I add a redirect along with the response->json

Comment: when you are returning json means you are writnig api so you shouldnt return any view or redirect

Comment: so how would i get the form to redirect me to a different page

Comment: if you want to redirect to another page or view with data you can use one of these:
 return view('your-view')
            ->with('data', $data)
or
return Redirect::to('/profile')->with('data', $data);
you should set action for your form and then in your controller use one of above lines